# Asking for something that isn't know at the time being

Tags: discussion, questions

"When will dart be available in chrome" was deleted.

There is no problem for me; it was a genuine question, since dart was new to me, but I could  understand the objections. Still, when the date is known, a question like "When will dart be natively supported by Chrome" in Google should also yield Stack Overflow. In order to do so, it's even better to have it ready and indexed beforehand. To have google hits on questions is one of the main goals of SO as far as I know.

In Stack Overflow the question was deleted, so Google will yield http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=75df0ee29ec2c6cb&hl=en this one and others, but no Stack Overflow when the question can be answered.

Why should not we be able to ask questions here that can only be answered in the, of course somewhat near, future?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question "when will X be available?" encourages speculation before an announcement and can only be answered by employees of the company producing X.

One year after X was made available the question "When will X be available?" looks *really* old and tired.

Thus the question is "too localized" - it is "only relevant to a specific instance in time".

Even when an officially announced date is known there would still be an aspect of "not constructive" - it encourages speculation about slippage of release schedules or the dropping of features.

This question would be reasonable somewhere more chatty (e.g. a forum or chat room), but Stack Overflow is trying to be a reference resource (think textbook/encyclopedia), not just another forum/chatroom, which makes localized questions a poor fit.

Comment: No it was "not a real question".  I agree once it will be outdated, but lots of other questions have the same problem without generating close-votes.

Comment: @Peter - I'd have closed as "too localized" personally, although "not a real question" makes sense for a question that can only be answered by employees of a specific company with privileged information. I have a suspicion the other non-closed questions are much older. The view on this has shifted quite a bit over the past few years.

Comment: tx for your insights

Answer (score 1):

The question was likely closed because of this reason:

**too localized**
"This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. "

It's better suited to chat-rooms I think. And it's not so clear, what's Dart ?

Comment: No : it was : "not a real question"

Comment: @Peter, the question was not suitable for a number of reasons. It was closed using the "not a real question" close reason, but it also qualified for "too localized" (as Adel and awoodland say) and "not constructive".

Comment: I agree (now), wasn't too clear to me first.

Answer (score 1):

To add what has been already said in the other answers, the FAQ reports the following sentence in [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

There isn't an actual problem to be solved, and the question is open-ended. You can cite different sources about when something will be available, including the direct interested (that are who are developing the product/technology), but the only way to know when something is available is to wait for it to be available; it would not be the first time that something was supposed to be available from a date, and it was then available later than that date.

Then, once the product/technology is available, the question doesn't interest anybody anymore.